# WebRequest and WebResponse loading very slow vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I have around 40 values in my database. I am checking every single url if it is online or offline. This is the function I am using:

```
Public Function CheckAddress(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean

        Try
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
End Function
```

But this is taking too much time. How can we load the page faster?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check for headers only, via the HEAD method:

```
Public Function CheckAddress(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        request.Method = "HEAD" ' only headers!
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        If response IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
             response.Headers IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
             response.Headers.count > 0                 
           ...
           ' check if you get anything
          Return True
        else
          Return false
        end if     
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

This may be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I added timeout to WebRequest. Like:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
request.Timeout = 50
```

Comment: But, this only will give a WebException if the URL is not accesed within the time-out period. I mean, you can get an exception for a valid URL.